# What is the best practice to save the one to many domain associated objects in grails?

Tags: grails

What is the best practice to save the one to many domain associated objects in grail?Lets consider a scenario.

If you have two classes A and B and A hasMany B relations and B belongsTo A , what is the best practice to create/save/delete the B domain object .As in many cases, its not possible to create B objects when As are created .

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

> its not possible to create B objects when As are created .

I'm pretty sure that's not true.  Grails uses Hibernate, and Hibernate has the notion of transitive persistence, which is basically the cascade settings.  By default, Grails has a cascade setting of `save-update`, which means that if you create a new parent, and a new child, and add the child to the parent, when you save the parent, the child should be saved.

There is no "best-practice".  You need to completely understand persistence semantics in hibernate, and chose the configuration that makes sense for you.  Do you want children to have their own lifecylces or not?  Which operations do you want to cascade?  Do you want the relationship to be bidirectional or not, and which way should the relationships go? Developing a good domain layer requires understanding these questions (and others like them), and the implications of the answers vis-a-vis the functionality you need.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure of what you are asking exactly, but if you are asking how to instantiate and save both As and Bs, i'd do it like this:

```
class B {
    String name
    static belongsTo=[a:A]
}

class A {
    static hasMany=[manyBs:B]
}
```

Then:

```
def a=new A()
a.addToManyBs(name:'someB')
a.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the objects Owner and Pet. Initialize an owner object with no pets and go ahead and save, just to demonstrate pets don't have to be created at the same time.

```
Owner owner = new Owner(pets: []).save()
```

Now we can add pets to the owner. We can do that with a single pet:

```
owner.pets.add(new Pet(name: "fido"))
```

Or we can use a collection of pets:

```
def petCollection = [
    new Pet(name: "Pete"),
    new Pet(name: "meow")
]
owner.pets.addAll(petCollection)
owner.save()
```

By saving the Owner object, you'll see that the newly created Pet objects are also persisted.

Answer (score 0):

you need to give nullable true in constraints part in domain.
i.e static constraints{
        a nullable: true
}